# Enabling the internal search in the sitecore analytics

Tags: experience-analytics, xconnect, tracking

I try to track the top searched keywords to my website using the Sitecore analytics, I read that first I need to register the search page event, So I wrote this :

```
if(Tracker.Current == null)
        {
            var result1 = Tracker.Enabled;
            Tracker.StartTracking();
        }

        var searchEvent = Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.PageEvents[AnalyticsIds.SearchEvent.Guid];

        var result = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(new PageEventData(searchEvent.Alias, searchEvent.Id)
        {
            Data = "Test Keyword 2"
        });
```

but still the internal search shows no data to display, I enabled the tracker and still the same problem, I'm using Sitecore 9

Comment: I believe for the internal search you need to set the Text property (at least that was the case in Sitecore 8)

Comment: @Trayek Can you please give me more details, as sitecore 9 uses new methods

Comment: var result = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(new PageEventData(searchEvent.Alias, searchEvent.Id)
        {
            Text = "Test Keyword 2"
        });

Comment: I did this and it works, the internal search show words but it's not updated, I think it's delayed or works at specific intervals

Comment: Is the tracker.StartTracking() working for you? Because to me it always says that analytics was not initialized

Comment: By the way the keywords will be delayed for 30 mins. unless you have to change your web.config to set this to 1 or 0 so it will be real time. :)

Comment: @HanzKristopherEnriquez , as long as I remember it worked for me, I just enabled the analytics, and thanks for the tip of the delayed time :)