# How do I enable the Internal Search reporting in Sitecore Analytics using the SXA search components?

Tags: sxa, experience-analytics

We are using Sitecore 9.0 and the SXA search components.

I have found a few articles that state that you need to register the button click event in the search page controller to turn this functionality on:  [Enabling the internal search in the sitecore analytics](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13022/enabling-the-internal-search-in-the-sitecore-analytics)

Since we are using the built-in Sitecore SXA Search components, how should this be implemented?  Do I need to override the search javascript files and add custom code in there to register the event?

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in to SXA already and should be working if you are using the OOTB SXA search results component. It works using the `RegisterSearchEventAttribute` MVC filter on the SXA `SearchController` which checks for a query string parameter for the search term. If one exists then it parses the value and will register the Search Page Event as long as the Tracker is initialized correctly.